# Send Multiple Data to Controller by using Javascript json

Tags: javascript

You will see items below side.I want to use items in my "Data".

Something like this.

**MyItemList : items**

How can i use items in data ?

```
var items = checkListBox3.GetSelectedItems();
alert(Array.prototype.map.call(items, function (item) {
return  item.value;
}).join(", "));

var data= {
Something: Something.GetValue(),
//My question here (I want to use above items here like MyList:items)
};

$.ajax({
url: "/Home/MyUrl",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(veri),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying exactly what the comment in your code said, and use `MyList:items`:

```
var data= {
   Something : Something.GetValue(),
   MyList : items
};
```